# how can I add a Target Type on SDL Web 8?

Tags: content-delivery, web8

could anyone tell me How can I add a Target Type on SDL Web8?

I created a Business Process Type, but when I clic on publish button, I had any target.

Where is the configuration to join aplication with target? (old Publication target)
where can I configure the connection between Content Manager and Deployer and choose the kind of transport? (old publication target)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the asociation inside of Publication's properties

Thanks

Comment: Could anyone tell me how to add multiple BPT to Publication?

Comment: You can create as many BPTs as you want in one Publication, but only one of them can be associated with publication. If you want to have multiple targets in one BPT you should firstly create CdTopologyType with multiple purposes and create a BPT based on it. It will create TargetType for each purpose.

Answer (score 2):

In order to see target types you need to associate your BPT with Publication.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably worth following the "[single machine guide](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-8789A353-267D-4466-9A6D-4CF6709E4E88)" that we shipped as part of the documentation.

It's also worth mentioning that the update coming on March 31st includes some additional scripts to automate this task and reduce the number of manual steps.